# Why do C variables have peculiar 40-bit memory addresses on Android 12?

Tags: android, c, memory

I have this simple code which prints the address of a variable to stdout:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a=0;
    printf ("Address of a: %p", (void*)&a);
    return 0;
}
```

Executing this code on an Android 11 (32-bit OS) device gives the output as:

```
Address of a: 0xffd7458c
```

which is a 32-bit memory address, as expected.

But executing this code on an Android 12 (64-bit OS, as far as I know) device gives the output as:

```
Address of a: 0x7fdfee014c
```

which is an unusual 40-bit memory address.

So my question is, shouldn't the memory addresses on Android 12 be 64-bit (i.e. something like `0x7fdfee014c346a5f`) as it is a 64-bit operating system?

A detailed explanation would be much appreciated.

Comment: That's like saying `3` isn't in the range `0` to `100`. If you use `%016p` you'll get your 64 bit value. Put another way, in a machine with 1000 address locations, you are saying that  addresses `100` to `999` are valid, and addresses `00` to `99` are somehow wrong.

Comment: simply 24 most significant bits are `zero`

Comment: Using ```%016p``` just adds leading zeroes before the number and after ```0x```, it doesn't add precision to the value. So it still remains a 40-bit address as I said.

Comment: Here is even worse only 24 bits :) https://godbolt.org/z/odj9rGWdY

Comment: It needs saying again: half of the addresses are 64-bit addresses. Half of those left are 63-bit addresses. Half of those left are 62-bit addresses... etc. The address you printed happens to be low down in the range of 64-bit addresses, and so it has leading zeros, which were automatically suppressed.

Comment: every 32-bit number is a 64-bit number, but sure not the other way around. You have no control over the address of a variable. `&a` could be  `0xffd7458c` on a 64-bit machine and you would not complain.

Comment: Okay I get it now, so does this mean that it's more compiler-specific, i.e. the compiler is assigning lower bit addresses to the variables, and it's technically possible for addresses like ```0x7fdfee014c346a5f``` to exist. Right?

Comment: And so the lowest possible address is ```0x0000000000000000``` (16 0's) and the highest is ```0xffffffffffffffff``` (16 f's). Right?

Comment: Did you see: https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/arm64/memory.html

Comment: Address `0x0000007fdfee014c` is a perfectly valid 64-bit address. Why do you think its only 40 bits?

Comment: Address 0x0000000000000000 is not a valid address, as its another way of saying `NULL`, which is the universal "invalid" address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless your 64-bit Android phone has 18 EXA-bytes of memory (that's 18 BILLION gigabytes), the memory map will be sparse. It would appear that your memory (RAM?) is mapped into the address space handled by 40-bits of address.